# Embed YouTube Video using MyToolkit Network connection crash Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, youtube, mytoolkit

I have used MyToolkit to Embed a Youtube Video in my Windows phone 8 application it works fine with network connection but when i turn off the WiFi and start the video in my app it crash, So i want to show a message to tell the user " No Network connection " and navigate back to "MainPage.xaml" instead of crashing, This is the code i use

```
private async void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var videoUri = await MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("Youtube_ID", MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTubeQuality.Quality480P, MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
    if (videoUri != null)
        player.Source = videoUri.Uri;              
}
```

and this is the Xaml code

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
     <mmppf:MediaPlayer x:Name="player" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"/>
</Grid>
```

Thanks

Comment: In which line does the crash occur? What's your question?

Comment: the crash occur when no connection detected so my question how to detect the connection and give a message to the user " No Network connection detected " and then navigate back to the main page i used this tutorial ( http://developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Community/2013/07/13/embed-youtube-videos-into-your-windows-phonewindows-8-app-2/)  but it doesn't say anything about this problem .

Answer (score 1):

try this 
 var videoUri = await MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("Youtube_ID", MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTubeQuality.Quality480P)

Answer (score 0):

Surround your await method in a try catch:

```
private async void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool videoSuccess = true;
    try {
    var videoUri = await MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("Youtube_ID", MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTubeQuality.Quality480P, MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
    if (videoUri != null)
        player.Source = videoUri.Uri; 
    }
    catch (Exception e) { // Debug and find out which exception is being thrown
    videoSuccess = false;    
    }
    if (videoSuccess == false) {
    await MessageDialog.ShowAsync("Video couldn't be played.","No Internet"); }                
    }
```